# Naming Sheets Name on ExportingExcel Feature of RDLC in VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have created .RDLC report in VS.Net 2010 and put group at first column and page break on that group.when my report gets generated and export that report into excel sheets names become as "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" but I want these sheets name will be as per the groupName.

Comment: Naming excel sheets based on grouping is outlined in this article:
http://www.bidn.com/blogs/PatrickLeBlanc/ssis/762/ssrs-r2-naming-excel-worksheet-tabs

Comment: @user883139  No, that is for RDL (Server side) not RDLC (Client side) I am having the same problem currently.

Comment: same here.. i know that RDLC does not support page naming but anybody here how to have a work around for this...